# MVP with interactor and repository + rxjava 2. Where to call observeOn and subscribeOn

Tags: android, rx-java2, mvp, clean-architecture

I have an Android app based on MVP + interactors + repositories. All layers from repository to presenter are wired using reactive streams (RxJava 2). View requests something from presenter, presenter asks from interactor, interactor asks from repository and repository asks from API itself. Response passes through the same layers as reactive stream from API to presenter. Each layer can map data for underlying layer.

The question is. Where should I call subscribeOn(io()/computation()/etc) and observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) ?
I think that observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) should be called from presenter because heavy computings could be performed in interactor.
In many examples subscribeOn(io()/computation()/etc) is called from presenter, but I don't agree with this approach. I think that presenter shouldn't decide in which thread to load data. Repository should decide in which thread to load data from API.
For example if we have the repository interface to load contacts. An implementation can get data from DB or Internet or in-memory storage. There is no need to create thread for in-memory repository. So repository should decide whether subscribe on io/computation/etc scheduler or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my openion multithreading stuff are not related to model and logics. They might differ by platforms, so I set the schedulers of streams in the presentation layer.

Comment: agree with @Malv its doesnt relate to architecture. Ususally i would subsbcribe in view and observe api responses in presenter.

Answer (score 2):

I would not call `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` in the repository layer for the following reasons:

- Methods that implicitly execute on different threads are very hard to use and may cause problems in the clients that are calling them.
- If you want to compose multiple streams coming from different repositories, it would be more convenient to have control over them. If they are subscribed on different threads, this may lead to subtle bugs, less than optimal performance and hard to read code.
- This adds another responsibility to the repo layer. Instead of being simple data stores, the repos are now aware of threads. In my opinion, this breaks the single responsibility principle.

I generally call `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` in the last layer before the views - in that case this will be your presenter layer. There I have full control over the composition of the interactors and better judgement over where I want to process things and where do I need the results of the processing.

Comment: Could you give me some examples for 1 and 2 reasons?
What about the third, I agree, but I'm not shure that presenter should manage threads.

Comment: What if I have two implementations of one repository interface? One of them just store data in RAM. There's no need to use separate thread to write or read data. Another implementation of repository uses SQLite. So it should use i/o scheduler  When I use subscribeOn in presenter I can't predict what implementation of repository uses interactor. That's why in my opinion repository should decide what scheduler to pick.

Comment: @Radik You are right, that the interactor shouldn't care about the specific implementation of a repo. But imagine this scenario - you are getting data from your cache repo and you call `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`. Then you `flatMap()` to another stream that performs a network request and you end up getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. The problem will not be obvious and not easy to debug.

Comment: @Radik Also, what happens if the implementation of a repo changes? The threading model will also change implicitly, without informing the clients, and this may lead to bugs. IMHO, it's better to have a common way of working with repo methods. Calling the local cache from another thread won't cause any errors, but making a network request on the wrong thread may blow up your app. Making the developer thing which method works on which thread will not be good.

Comment: I defenetely should call observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) from presenter. The main question was about where to call subscribeOn(...). AFAIK I won't get NetworkOnMainThreadException if I flatMap from a stream of cache's repo to another stream that performs a network request